# Gradle C plugin: how to solve references between multiple modules

Tags: c, gradle

I have a c language program that has the following structure:

```
src/main/c/main.c
src/main/headers/main.h
src/module_1/c/module_1.h
src/module_1/headers/module_1.h
...
src/modulen/c/module_n.c
src/module/headers/module_n.h
```

In the gradle script I have defined:

```
components {
   module_1(NativeLibrarySpec)
   ...
   module_n(NativeLibrarySpec)
   main(NativeExecutableSpec){
      sources{
        c.lib library: "module_1", linkage: "static"
        ...
        c.lib library: "module_n", linkage: "static"
   }
```

The reason of using this structure is to facilitate creating unit tests for each module separately.

The problem comes with the inclusion of the .h files from the modules in the main or in other modules (there are some dependencies between them). I haven't found a way to make the headers of a module available to other modules. I would actually like to make them all "global" to the project (that is, automatically added to the source set for any module).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not know gradle but may give you some general advise.

> I haven't found a way to make the headers of a module available to other modules.

You could make a central directory (repository) for all `.h` files of your project, for example `src/include`. The header files of each module can be placed there (in the version of the curent baseline).

> I would actually like to make them all "global" to the project (that is, automatically added to the source set for any module).

The above repository can support that. However, including a header in a source file is a manual task. It is also wise not to include all headers into a source file; it may only need a few.